# Access changed variables across modules

Tags: python

I have three modules A, B  and C

In A

```
 state = "yada yada"
 def up(msg):
     global state
     state = msg
```

In B

```
import A       
text = "nana nana"
C.up(text)
```

In C

```
   import A
   print A.state
```

Which prnits "yada yada". How do I get it to print "nana nana"?

Comment: First of all, by importing `B` somewhere? Does that not work?

Comment: Do you just run `C`? That imports `A`, so `A` gets run once as well. But how do you expect `B` to get run?

Comment: What is the actual content of `B`? The code that you provide should error.

Comment: You can't access `C` from `B` unless it uses `import C`.

Comment: `up` is defined in `A`, so `C.up` should be `A.up`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what you are trying to accomplish where you are calling "C.up(text)", you need to adjust your file import chain and also provide some additional function definitions.  In order to get your desired outcome, B.py needs to import C.py, and C.py needs to import A.py.  And since you are referencing the "up" function for the import of C.py, that file needs to have that function defined.  With all of that, here is what the files probably should look like in order to produce the desired results.

```
# This is A.py

state = "yada yada"
def up(msg):
    global state
    state = msg

# This is C.py

import A

def up(msg):
    A.up(msg)
    print(A.state)  # Notice the indentation here

# This is B.py

import C      
text = "nana nana"
C.up(text)
```

When I revised the files, I got the expected output.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/ABC$ python3 B.py 
nana nana
```

Try those bits out and see if that allows you to move forward.

Comment: Yeah, importing them that way is one solution, unfortunately one of the modules is a long running background/process thing, so I had to put it in main in a thread ultimately. I  was trying to avoid that.